# Detecting and Retrieving text from a column based on language model in R

Tags: r, language-detection

I am using `googleLanguageR` to detect automatically text language from a text column from a data frame. For a particular sentence, I do the following:

```
library(googleLanguageR)
gl_auth("credential.json")

gl_translate_detect(df[[45, 'text']])
```

where `text` is a column in data frame `df`. `45` is the line number for which I want to detect the language. "credential.json" is a private API key from Google.

Which gives me the corresponding detected language as output. However, I want to apply for the entire text column which has mixed texts in English and German language and to get them separate.

I tried the following:

```
gl_translate_detect(df[['text']])
```

But gives me:

```
Error in nchar(string) : invalid multibyte string, element 13
```

My idea is to feed a corpus to detect the underlying language on a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be vectorized.  We can use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(out = tryCatch(gl_tranlsate_detect(text), 
     error = function(e) NA_character_))
```

---

Or with `lapply` to loop over each of the elements in 'text' column and apply the function

```
lapply(df$text, gl_translate_detect)
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, However, it gives me the following:

```
Error in dplyr::mutate(., out = gl_translate_detect(text)) : 
ℹ The error occurred in row 49.
Caused by error in `nchar()`:
! invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

Comment: @RanjiRaj if there are cases that return errors, you may wrap with `tryCatch` as in the updated solution